# Unable to open external link in safari using WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate, wkuidelegate

I am migrating from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`. Need to load HTML content in `WKWebView` everything is working fine but the problem is unable to open link in the external safari browser after a click on any link from `WKWebView`. I used below code

Class

```
class CTFSPolicyAndTermsViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {}
```

outlet and `WKWebView` variable

```
  @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!
  var webView: WKWebView!
```

`viewDidLoad` method

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView()
    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView =  WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
   [webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.topAnchor),
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.bottomAnchor),
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.leftAnchor),
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.rightAnchor)].forEach  { 
     anchor in
    anchor.isActive = true
    }
```

for loading the HTML Content

```
     if(self.isTermsMode)
        {

            let path:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "abc", ofType: "html")!
            let text = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webView!.loadHTMLString(text!, baseURL: nil)
        }
```

decidePolicyFor

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            print(url)
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)  
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
       }
    }
```

`decidePolicyFor` method should call but it's not executing I am unable to find the problem

Comment: Are you sure that HTML is OK? It's not get inside `decidePolicyFor ` on tap?

Comment: Yes, i put the break point over decidePolicyFor

Comment: My suggestion is to try to load another page (f.e. google.com) to debug is it a problem with the delegate method or with HTML.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @Andrew everything was fine just was in wrong position now it's working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was missing the order

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView =  WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    [webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.topAnchor),
     webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.bottomAnchor),
     webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.leftAnchor),
     webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
      webViewContainer.rightAnchor)].forEach  { anchor in
        anchor.isActive = true
    }
    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```